# What methods (if any) are available for differentiating between true population variance and variance caused by measurement error?

Tags: standard-deviation, measurement-error

This may be a question of philosophy or metrology, but I'd like to know if there are any methods that are available to differentiate between variance that is caused by a true spread in the population and variance that is as result of imprecise measurements.

Example:

Imagine you have a population with a property of interest that you have reason to believe is normally distributed. Let's make this concrete and say it is the strength of some manufactured plastic. You have some measurement equipment that characterizes this strength, but it is suspected that the equipment yields only imprecise measurements. The measurement precision tolerance of the equipment is unknown. You know that the plastics are heterogeneous on the same scale as the measurement equipment, so you expect that there will be some variation in the measurement that is due to the individual plastic samples being different.

So, you make a series (more than one and enough to fit to a distribution) of measurements, fit them to a normal distribution and extract a sample mean and sample variance. Let's further say you calculate errors on the mean and variance using some robust method.

You might suspect that a component of the sample variance is due to issues with error in the measurement and some of it is due to the actual population distribution.

Then you take another series of measurements on what you *have reason to believe* is the same population, i.e. it is the same lot of manufactured plastic or something like that. The result of your second set of measurements is another sample mean and sample variance, and you again calculate errors on the mean and variance. You find that the sample mean or sample variance (or both) differ between the two sets of measurements by greater than the error on the mean and/or variance. That is, you would conclude that there is a significant difference between the two sets measurements. They look like two different populations.

Now let's say you get serious and want to figure out what the fundamental equipment precision is. So you get a *standard*: a material that you've tried to construct so that the different individual samples are as identical as you can possibly make them. You **don't** know *a priori* what the measurement of the standard should be, but you have really good reason to believe that the individual samples are as identical as is physically possible.

You again do a set of measurements and get sample mean/variance and errors on the parameters. You find that the sample variance on the standard is *larger* than it is for your heterogeneous, manufactured plastic. That is, according to the test, the **standard** has a higher variance than your material under test.

You do another set of measurements on the standard, again get a sample mean/variance and the parameter errors. And like the two measurements on heterogeneous plastic, you find that the two sample means and/or variances have a statistically significant difference. Again, the sample variance for the **standard** *is larger* than that of the heterogeneous plastic.

So just to give a visual, the situation might look something like the graphs below:

[image]

[image: Possible sample variance from my description]

*Note: these are completely made up for the example.

In all cases, you've tried to keep your measurement methodology uniform (e.g. same number of samples in each set of measurements, etc.). You've conduct all the measurements on the same equipment. You have no other way to "calibrate" the equipment other than the measurement on the standard (which as mentioned, you do not have an *a priori* value for what the measurement should yield).

Further, there are no alternative "gold standard" tests that you can go to for a better answer. The test that exists is the only one that measures this property and is the *de facto* best measurement. There are other sets of testing rigs (e.g. physically different pieces of equipment), but they all implement the same type of test.

Given these measurements, parameter fits and errors on the parameters, what, if anything, can one conclude about the true population variance of the plastic and the measurement precision of the equipment? Are there any follow-up tests that could be conducted to elucidate more information about the equipment precision or the population variance?

Comment: Assuming that you've run the tests a second time to help convince that you have not suffered from the occasional misleading sample, if the standard that you've make every attempt to make consistent gives more variability than the samples then you've found yourself in impossible land! No inferences about anything can be reliably made there.

Comment: @Michael Lew: +1 for the occasional misleading example. 
@ user218912: Something in your hand made graphs puzzles me: sigma for the left plastic material was smaller than for the right one, but you still have larger error bars for the mean for the left plastic. Have the sample sizes been different? or is it just due to drawing by hand?

Comment: To answer Ute: The graph was just made as an example to try to put a visual with the hypothetical. Don't read to much into anything about the specifics.

Comment: To answer Lew: in my example, I only considered four measurements. For the system I'm thinking of, there are many many more on both materials under test and the standard. This is the general character of the measurement.

Comment: I think @MichaelLew is right, his comment should be the answer. One could add that additional sources of variation are measurement under slightly different conditions, such as week days, temperature and the like. To avoid that noise from these conditions obscure the signal, one should use a proper experimental design and measure both the standard and the heterogeneous under the same conditions.